# glob() return in an empty array

Tags: php, glob

Im trying to set a array containing all the image files in a directory, ive got my index.php set up in the same directory as the images. The code im using is

```
$images = glob("*.jpg, *jpeg, *.png, *.gif");

var_dump($images);
```

which returns - `array(0) { }` in the browser.. any idea what im doing wrong ?

sorry if this is such an obvious question im still very green to php

Comment: You probably have to specify the full path.

Comment: Does this have to be done even if the image files are in the same directory as the script file ?

Comment: See the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) manual page again. Just throwing in commas is not a valid syntax for specifying alternative file extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `GLOB_BRACE` from PHP doc :

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.
>
> [GLOB_BRACE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

Example:

```
$directory = __DIR__;
$images = glob("$directory/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($images);
```